# Creating a list of numbers one through nth Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

How can I create a list one through nth that gives me a list, that is only one digit in length. So 100 would be 1,0,0 and 19 would be 1,9

```
>>> listGen(20)


>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,0,1,1,1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6,1,7,1,8,1,9,2,0]
```

Comment: Can you show your code attempt at this and explain what is not working out for you?

Comment: I can't figure it out, that is why I posted it here with no code.

Comment: Next time please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To put together a more complete question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def listgen(n):
    return map(int, ''.join(map(str, range(1, n + 1))))
```

**Breaking it apart:**

```
n = 10
a = range(1, n + 1)   # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = map(str, a)       # ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']
c = ''.join(b)        # '12345678910'
d = map(int, c)       # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0]
```

The above code is written for python 2. For python 3 you could convert the `map` to `list`.

Comment: `range` starts at 0, by the way, not 1.

Comment: You know you can specify a start with `range(1, n+1)`, right? You don't have to slice it.

Comment: Thanks. Updated it again :)

Answer (score 1):

Or, without map()...

```
>>> [int(c) for c in ''.join([str(n) for n in range(1,21)])]
```

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1, 8, 1, 9, 2, 0]